# Unable to ping between host machines and guest vms running on Vmware

Tags: networking, centos, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

In order to learn a bit about system administration, I've installed a Centos vm using Vmware on my local machine running Windows 7. Everything *seems* to be working fine since I can access the internet from the Centos machine, but I am unable to ping the host machine from the vm or vice versa. I get the message "destination host unreachable". I also have a win7 vm and I run into the same problem when attempting to ping between it and the host. There's a third computer on the network which is able to ping both of the vms and the host machine. The vms are also able to ping this other computer. The only problem I have with pinging seems to happen between the host and the vms. When I switch the vm network adapter over to NAT, the problem goes away and I'm able to ping successfully.

As I understand it, this should be working since the bridged vm is supposed to act like another physical device on the network.

Comment: maybe firewall on win 7 is blocking icmp packets. Also try to stop firewall on the linux - "service iptables stop"

Comment: I tried disabling all the firewalls. I'm pretty sure that's not the problem though, since the pinging works between all computers except between the host and the vms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AHA! After over 10 hours of trying to figure this out, I finally got it.

All I had to do was disable the "DNE LightWeight Filter" by right-clicking my network adapter and going to properties. This is apparently a driver by the company Citrix, which must have been installed for the SonicWall vpn I use.

Comment: If you ever come back to this place: accept your own answer to mark it solved.

Comment: Great, at last I found a solution

Comment: Which network adapter was this, host or guest?

Comment: @JayImerman, this was on the host

Answer (score 2):

In most cases this is Firewall who is causing troubles. Try to turn it off on the host and virtual machine and ping it again, than if it helps, turn it back on and  configure Firewall rules accordingly.

Comment: U r the boss :D

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit -> Virtual Network Editor and try to change your bridged network adapter (don't use automatic)

Comment: you saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

Change the connection from NAT to bridge and check replicate bla...blaa,
and then login to Ubuntu VM and on the right bottom, there was network adapter, just disconnect and connect again.